# Puppet keeps trying to install mongrel

Tags: ruby, puppet, mongrel

I'm using Puppet to administrate my servers and one of the things I'm doing is installing Mongrel from the Gem:

```
package { mongrel: 
  provider => gem,
  ensure => latest,
  require => Package[rubygems],
}
```

but it seems there's some issue because Puppet keeps trying to install Mongrel in every run. I get tons of these from Puppet:

```
notice: /Stage[main]/Passenger/Package[mongrel]/ensure: ensure changed '1.1.5' to '1.1.5 ruby java x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32-60'
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks very much like a bug. I would file a bug report.

A workaround might be :

```
ensure => "1.1.5"
```

ensure => "latest" is always dangerous on anything but test servers.

Comment: I disagree about fixing to one version (not strongly though) because I'm not doing full time administration of these servers and if there's a critical bug that gets fixed, I'd rather get the fix automatically than wait until I get to know about it (which may be too late). Other than that, I've reported the bug: https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/5215

Comment: I would recommend using `ensure => installed` and then have a regular update schedule (preferably automated).  Should be best of both worlds.